# Remove ongoing notification from service

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-notifications

I have a service that create a notification when it is started.

And then ondestroy() i want it to be removed.

I just use .cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);

It works great when it is a normal notification but when i am using ongoing event it just won't cancel it.

I did read something about that services doesn't stop if android have the resources for it, but how to overcome this?

I use this code to start the service

```
    final Intent bg_service = new Intent(BackgroundService.class.getName());

    btn_start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
    btn_stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);

    btn_start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startService(bg_service);
        }
    });

    btn_stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopService(bg_service);
        }
    });
```

I use this in on create

```
            notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
            getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            "A new notification", System.currentTimeMillis());

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE;

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, mainapp.class);
    PendingIntent activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "...",
            "...", activity);
    notificationManager.notify(19314, notification);
```

And this in on destroy

```
            noficationManager.cancel(19314);
```

Comment: Can you show some code where you are starting your `Service`?

Comment: And how do you add the ongoing notification?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would look at doing 'ongoing' notifications a bit differently if you can.  There are methods that live on `Service` that are dedicated to adding and removing an 'ongoing' notification.

[`Service.startForeground(int, Notification)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29)

[`Service.stopForeground(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopForeground%28boolean%29)

Perhaps you could just try calling `stopForegroud(boolean)` from your `onDestroy()` method first...

Comment: perfect. Just what i was looking for. Thanks!